# Connection of phidgets accelerometer using Android OS

Tags: java, android, usb, sensors

I'm newbie in Android (and programming) and I would like to connect an USB Phidgets accelerometer ([product description](http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=5&product_id=1059)) using Android OS. On his website, Phidgets gives code samples including JAVA and others (see previous hyperlink). Could someone tell me if these samples are supposed to work with Android OS ? Any other suggestions to achieve this goal kepping Android and using other accelerometer and/or programming language ?

Comment: Just because it's in java doesn't mean it'll work on Android.  I would suggest looking into how to connect to USB devices in Android